# package clash between ctable and auto-pst-pdf?

Tags: pdftex, auto-pst-pdf, ctable

I'm new to LaTeX and decided to write my PhD thesis with it (pdflatex.exe, TexStudio2.6.6, Win7x64).

I nailed the conflict to two packages namely `ctable` and `auto-pst-pdf`.
Unfortunately I need both packages and I hope it is a small problem.

Here we go. If I use an `X` specifier in a table with a `width` option, then `latex.exe` in taskmanager is very busy and no output is processed within 30 minutes until I kill the task. If no `X` specifier is used in a `ctable` command, no odd behavior occurrs. Maybe this is a system specific problem of my installation.

I've prepared a MWE with a table typeset with the `tabularx` environment and one typeset with the `ctable` command; `tabularx` works fine with the `X` specifier and `auto-pst-pdf` activated. What is going on?

Thanks so much for your attention and assistance.

```
\documentclass[plain,english,a4paper,12pt,headsepline]{scrbook}

\usepackage{ifplatform}
\usepackage{pst-xkey}
%\usepackage[runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{ctable} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{MWE with tabularx}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXll}
\FL                         
\textbf{A}  &   \textbf{B}  &   \textbf{C}      &   \textbf{D}  
\ML                         
a   &   b   &   c   &   1   \NN
a   &   b   &   c   &   1   
\LL 
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\ctable[
caption = MWE with ctable,
notespar,
width = \textwidth
]
{XXll}
{
\tnote[a]{aaa}
\tnote[b]{bbb}
\tnote[c]{ccc}
.}
{
\FL                         
\textbf{A}  &   \textbf{B}  &   \textbf{C}      &   \textbf{D}  
\ML                         
a   &   b   &   c   &   1   \NN
a   &   b   &   c   &   1   
\LL                     
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: [ctable | Table not compilable with every Compiler Engine](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&p=70222). At least with TeX Live 2013, I can verify that `xelatex` builds this document correctly, but since there's no real use of `auto-pst-pdf` in it, it might not work in your real document.

Comment: I'm not a fan of `ctable`; perhaps `threeparttable` can be considered.

Comment: ok, thanks anyway! there is a workaround in the link you ve posted.

Comment: well i need a couple of features:concerning `threeparttable`, am i able to include tablefootnotes in one line under the table? how can i rotate the table clockwise to landscape mode?

Comment: OK, nice: i use the `[para]`option in `\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}` for typesetting the tablenotes in one line. the rotate package `\usepackage{rotating}` enables the `sidewaystable`environment, thus rotating big tables to landscape style. done! no need for ctable...